# What is Chart Colors in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

While making theme I saw this

```
    "charts.blue": "#ff0000",
    "charts.green": "#ff0000",
    "charts.orange": "#ff0000",
    "charts.purple": "#ff0000",
    "charts.red": "#ff0000",
    "charts.yellow": "#ff0000",
    "charts.lines": "#ff0000",
    "charts.foreground": "#ff0000"
```

What does it Do? 
&
What is charts in VSCode

Answer (score 0):

The first column is the defined **name** of the specific color for the chart item, the second column is the actual value of the color.

see the [official docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color#chart-colors).

[image]